# What is the logical error in my buildHeap function?

Tags: c++, heap, heapsort

I am trying to construct a minheap from an existing vector.
My heapifyDown, HeapifyUp, insert, and extractMin functions seem to work fine - For example, I can use them to populate an empty array and retrieve the min.

But my buildHeap function seems incorrect. I can't figure out the logical error.

```
class MinHeap{
    void heapifyDown(int index,vector<int> &array){
        int leftIndex = 2*index + 1;
        int rightIndex = 2*index + 2;
        if(rightIndex < array.size()){
            int smallerIndex = (array[leftIndex] < array[rightIndex] ? leftIndex : rightIndex);
            if(array[index] > array[smallerIndex]){
                swap(array[index],array[smallerIndex]);
                heapifyDown(smallerIndex,array);
            }
        }else if(leftIndex < array.size()){
           if(array[index] > array[leftIndex]){
                swap(array[index],array[leftIndex]);
                heapifyDown(leftIndex,array);
            }
        }
    }
    
    void heapifyUp(int index,vector<int> &array){
        int parent = (index - 1)/2;
        if(array[index]<array[parent]){
            swap(array[index],array[parent]);
            heapifyUp(parent,array);
        }
    }
    
public:
    int extractMin(vector<int> &array){
        int min = -1;
        if(array.size()>0){
            min = array[0];
            array[0] = array[array.size()-1];
            array.pop_back();
            if(array.size()>0)
            heapifyDown(0,array);
        }
        return min;
    }
    
    void insert(int value,vector<int> &array){
        array.push_back(value);
        heapifyUp((int)array.size()-1,array);
    }
    
    void buildHeap(vector<int> &array){
        int startIndex = (int)array.size()/2 -1;
        for(int i=startIndex; i >=0; i--){
            heapifyDown(i,array);
        }
    }
};
```

What is logically incorrect about my buildHeap function ?

The objective of the buildHeap function is to take an existing vector of numbers and convert it into a minheap.

The problem is that the buildHeap function does not convert the vector into a valid heap, and instead fills it with incorrect numbers.

An example of max-Heapify is here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_and_analysis_of_algorithms/design_and_analysis_of_algorithms_heapify_method.htm

I am trying to do the same, but with a minHeap instead of a maxHeap.

Comment: What's wrong with the function? Please provide a [mre] with the expected and actual results

Comment: @AlanBirtles instead of converting the vector into a valid heap, it does not return a heap. There is some logical error in the algorithm. I have included a link to what the algorithm for heapifying a maxHeap is. I am trying to do the same, but for a minHeap.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] if you want us to debug your code for you

Comment: Why don't you add the example input & calls to these functions that the illustrate what you are saying?